# Swap keyboard numbers to symbols

Tags: perl, keyboard

I'm a programmer and recently diagnosed with carpal tunnel. I spend a majority of time programming in perl and just the nature of the language has me constantly reaching for my shift-key all day to grab my $, @, % symbols..

Does anyone know of a way to re-map keyboard keys so that the number keys and symbols are inverted? For example, I'd like to press 2 and get an @ symbol, press 5 and get %, and have the numbers require pressing shift. Basically the opposite of how these keys normally work.

A windows-based solution is preferred, but willing to go with a linux (Red Hat) solution if that is my only option.

Edit: I know there is a way to do this in Vi, however I typically use Komodo and other GUI-ish IDE's. Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you clarify which OSes you are seeking solutions for.

Comment: [This](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/carpalx/?carpalx_installation) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make your own keyboard layout with the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator. You can use it like any other Windows keyboard layout. It will work in all applications on Windows.

I know people who use it to have German Umlauts on a US keyboard layout. Changing the number keys should be no problem.

You can download it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Looking further:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yfdr11LQlvU
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slr-mYDUUsE

Comment: Glad it helps. Hope You'll get better :)